# Co-kriging in R

Tags: r, interpolation, spatial-statistics, geostatistical-analyst

I am trying to do co-kriging for my rainfall with arsenic data. Arsenic is a target variable. I have used the code below to generate an interpolation grid, but I was not able to generate the co-kriged map because of fitting a variogram I think. Could any one help me?

Here is the code:

```
# necessary package installation
library(gstat)
library(sp)
library(rgeos)
library(maptools)
library(rasterize)
library(raster)
library(lattice)
library(geoR)

# setting file location and working directory

setwd("C:/Users/c/Downloads/Documents")
Radata <- read.csv("raindata.csv", TRUE, ",")
ubngrid <- read.csv("UBNgridded.csv", TRUE, ",")


# converting the raw data into spatial classes

coordinates(Radata) = ~ X + Y
coordinates(ubngrid) = ~ X + Y
proj4string(Radata) <-CRS("+proj=utm +zone=37 +datum=WGS84")
proj4string(ubngrid) <-CRS("+proj=utm +zone=37 +datum=WGS84")

# to rasterize the interpolation grid


rast <- raster(ncol = 42, nrow = 49)
extent(rast) <- extent(ubngrid)
rasterize(ubngrid, rast, fun = mean)
class(ubngrid)


# use variogram cloud to set the cutoff, width, and bins

str(Radata$Ar)

plot(arvar.c <-
       variogram(
         Ar ~ 1,
         data = Radata,
         cutoff = 500000,
         cloud = T
       )) # generates variogram cloud
plot(ar.var <-
       variogram(
         Ar ~ 1,
         data = Radata,
         cutoff = 500000,
         width = 64500
       ),
     pl = T)

# The cutoff represents the maximal spatial distance taken into account between two observations (Range).
# The width is the distance interval over which the semi-variance is calculated (bin size).

# generate estimated variogram for target variable (arsenic)

m.ar <- vgm(2, "Sph", 250000, 1.5)
plot(ar.var, pl = T, model = m.ar)

# Fit the model parameters by weighted least-squares and plot on the empirical variogram for target variable:

(m.ar.f <- fit.variogram(ar.var, m.ar))
plot(ar.var, pl = T, model = m.ar.f)
rm(arvar.c, ar.var, m.ar)


#  ordinary krigging for only arsenic

k.o <-
  krige(Ar ~ 1, Radata, newdata = ubngrid, model = m.ar.f) # have to be checked
summary(k.o)


# plot.kresults(k.o,"var1",ubngrid,"Ar")
levelplot(var1.pred ~ X + Y,
          as.data.frame(k.o),
          aspect = "iso",
          main = "Ar prediction")
levelplot(var1.var ~ X + Y,
          as.data.frame(k.o),
          aspect = "iso",
          main = "Ar prediction variance")


# for the covariable (i.e rainfall)

v.ra <-
  variogram(obstrans ~ 1, Radata, cutoff = 500000, width = 90000)
plot(v.ra, pl = T)
m.rain <- vgm(0.02, "Sph", 250000, 0)
m.rain.f <- fit.variogram(v.ra, m.rain)
plot(v.ra, pl = T, model = m.rain.f)
summary(m.rain.f)

# to plot the ordinary kriging for rainfall

k.o <-
  krige(obstrans ~ 1, Radata, newdata = ubngrid, model = m.rain.f)
summary(k.o)

levelplot(var1.pred ~ X + Y,
          as.data.frame(k.o),
          aspect = "iso",
          main = "Rainfall prediction")
levelplot(var1.var ~ X + Y,
          as.data.frame(k.o),
          aspect = "iso",
          main = "Rainfall prediction variance")

# building gstat structure containing two sample sets

g <- gstat(NULL,
           id = "Ar",
           form = Ar ~ 1,
           data = Radata)
g <- gstat(g,
           id = "obstrans",
           form = obstrans ~ 1,
           data = Radata)
v.cross <- variogram(g)
plot(v.cross)
str(v.cross)
plot(v.cross, pl = T)

# add a variogram models to the gstat

g <- gstat(g,
           id = "Ar",
           model = m.ar.f,
           fill.all = T)
g <- fit.lmc(v.cross,
             g,
             fit.method = 6,
             correct.diagonal = 1.01)
plot(variogram(g), model = g$model)

# predict arsenic (Ar) on the interpolation grid

cokrigmodel <- predict(g, ubngrid)
str(cokrigmodel)


# plotting the result of cokrigging

# plot.kresults(cokrigmodel, "Ar", Radata, "CK of Ar with RF covariable",)

levelplot(
  cov.Ar.obstrans ~ X + Y,
  as.data.frame(cokrigmodel),
  aspect = "iso",
  main = "Ar.Rf prediction"
)
```

When I check the structure of the cokriging variogram the following is shown (I don't now why NA values are generated):

```
> str(cokrigmodel)
Formal class 'SpatialPointsDataFrame' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
  ..@ data       :'data.frame': 2058 obs. of  5 variables:
  .. ..$ Ar.pred        : num [1:2058] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  .. ..$ Ar.var         : num [1:2058] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  .. ..$ obstrans.pred  : num [1:2058] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  .. ..$ obstrans.var   : num [1:2058] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  .. ..$ cov.Ar.obstrans: num [1:2058] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..@ coords.nrs : int [1:2] 1 2
  ..@ coords     : num [1:2058, 1:2] 93047 93047 93047 93047 93047 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2058] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "X" "Y"
  ..@ bbox       : num [1:2, 1:2] 93047 929543 503047 1409543
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "X" "Y"
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "min" "max"
  ..@ proj4string:Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. ..@ projargs: chr NA
```

And finally when I try to plot the result of the cokriging, the following error has showed up:
Error in seq.default(zrng[1], zrng[2], length.out = cuts + 2) :
'from' must be a finite number
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
here is the data:
RaData:

```
structure(list(X = c(292722.66, 292722.66, 347471.84, 331697.62, 
                     347308.09, 353000.68, 472622.24, 461595.36, 467048.61, 373573.47, 
                     329853.95, 221532.11, 330428.43, 319514.95, 314044.23, 324985.55, 
                     341345.11, 202653.33, 214451.07, 368598.76, 352241.31, 241704.19, 
                     258066.2, 236060.39, 357179.46, 5e+05, 170390.47, 111692.65, 
                     161189.76, 390750.98, 314386.44, 379824.88, 123283.36, 93047.35, 
                     280376.32, 291732.42, 445359.1, 280634.02, 192294.72, 236060.39
), Y = c(1266419.32, 1266419.32, 1304819.32, 1404460.8, 1271637.56, 
         1321383.37, 1133064.21, 1061207.17, 1022505.54, 989521.73, 1050511.46, 
         1239297.88, 1172173.82, 1177760.59, 1177790.16, 1177731.91, 1166591.08, 
         929542.94, 1040134.26, 1138827.91, 1155482.53, 1006746.05, 984515.35, 
         984652.09, 1017222.82, 1000380.05, 1029415.07, 1196121.75, 1217729.6, 
         1216161.36, 1238628.64, 1216199.57, 1251375.28, 996909.86, 1039701.79, 
         1106012.3, 1204967.51, 1083951.79, 1018166.55, 984652.09), obstrans = c(3.194, 
                                                                                 3.194, 3.164, 3.068, 3.102, 3.164, 2.948, 2.948, 3.076, 3.011, 
                                                                                 3.011, 2.987, 3.132, 3.132, 3.132, 3.132, 3.132, 3.316, 3.316, 
                                                                                 3.132, 3.132, 3.316, 3.316, 3.316, 3.143, 3.031, 3.052, 3.009, 
                                                                                 3.124, 3.124, 3.124, 3.124, 3.124, 3.157, 3.157, 3.142, 3.142, 
                                                                                 3.295, 3.316, 3.316), Ar = c(3.2, 5, 4.1, 0.5, 2.9, 0.2, 0.2, 
                                                                                                              1.2, 0.9, 2.5, 3.1, 0.7, 0.2, 0.3, 2.9, 2.1, 0.9, 2.6, 3, 1.7, 
                                                                                                              3.8, 7, 3.6, 2.9, 0.9, 2.5, 3.1, 0.7, 0.2, 0.3, 2.9, 2.1, 0.9, 
                                                                                                              2.6, 3, 1.7, 3.8, 7, 3.6, 2.9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                   -40L))
```

Grid profile summary: RasterLayer dimensions : 49, 42, 2058 (nrow, ncol, ncell) resolution : 9761.905, 9795.918 (x, y) extent : 93047, 503047, 929543, 1409543 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax) crs : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 source : memory names : layer values : 1, 2058 (min, max)

Comment: The first error I get is with `proj4string(Radata) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")` "Geographical CRS given to non-conformant data:  500000.0 1404460.8" - those cooordinate numbers are way too large to be latitude-longitude, which is what EPSG:4326 is. Also, we don't have your `ubngrid` data or file, so we can't run your code as you do.

Comment: The coordinate numbers are in UTM. Is there any option to send you my ubngrid data? I didn't attached to the post because of limitation of character length.

Comment: If the coordinates are in UTM then you should set the projection to the correct EPSG code for the UTM zone. As written, your code shouldn't get past that line so how are you getting problems with the rest of it? If you can share files on Dropbox, OneDrive, or another sharing service that would be useful.

Comment: I didn't have the error before but after you told me then i tried to transform it after loading rgdal package, then the error you mentioned came and i coudn't go any further.  I would try to send you through one drive.

Comment: i have attached it on your gmail.

Comment: Also i have edited the code by setting the projection to UTM.